# How to use hashes correctly in perl class

Tags: perl

I learned to create a new class like this, with a hash as part of the instantiation:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my( $response, $config ) = @_;

    my $self = {
       _response => $response
       _config => $config
    };

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub getConfig {
  my( $self ) = @_;
  return $self->{_config};
}

sub getResponse {
  my( $self ) = @_;
  return $self->{_response};
}
```

When I create the class I send some configuration to it on instantiation.

```
my $response = {
  "my" => "response"
}

my $config = {
  "my" => "config"
}

$inst = MyClass::Class->new($response, $config);
```

When I get that information back it seems to work fine.

```
Data::Dumper

print Dumper $insta->getConfig();

$VAR = {
  "my" => "config"
}
```

Now it turns out that the config hash i'm being given looks like this:

```
%R_CONFIG = (
   "my", "config"
);
```

When I put that into my codebase all hell breaks loose:

```
$inst = Class->new($response, %config);
```

Im clearly making some fundamental mistakes. And I cant seem to get any solid information back from debugging, because everything is still saying its a hash when I use say `ref()` for example.

What mistake have I made with the creation of this class in regards to hashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass scalars to subs.

```perl
$inst = Class->new($response, %config);
```

is the same as

```perl
$inst = Class->new($response, "my", "config");
```

Your method expects a reference to a hash, so you should be using

```perl
$inst = Class->new($response, \%config);
```